# Need AVPlayerView to exit fullscreen on esc button press

Tags: macos, cocoa, video, swift, avfoundation

I'm new to swift, and Cocoa, coming from a JavaFX background.  I've build my first Mac OS app in Xcode 6.1 and it utilizes an AVPlayerView.  I have configured the AVPlayerView to provide a full screen button.  When a video is playing, pressing the full screen icon causes the player to go full screen.  I'm looking for a way to cause the escape button to make the AVPlayerView to go back to non-full screen.

Here's my code so far:

```
//subclassed AVPlayerView in an attempt to capture keystrokes
class VideoPlayerView: AVPlayerView, NSWindowDelegate {

    var lastPlayValue = true   //used in toggling play on space
    var ifs = false;           //variable holding "is full screen"

    //overrode this to get keystrokes
    override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    //thought this would be called when full screen is entered  
    //but it isn't
    func windowDidEnterFullScreen(notification: NSNotification) {
        ifs = true
        println("Entered full screen")
        //attempting to grab keyevents while in full screen
        becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    //thought this would be called when full screen has exited
    //but it isn't
    func windowDidExitFullScreen(notification: NSNotification) {
        ifs = false;
        //attempting to grab key events after full screen exited
        becomeFirstResponder()
        println("Exited Fullscreen")

    }


    //grabs key events.  Works when not in full screen mode
    override func keyUp(theEvent: NSEvent) {

       //handle events here.

    } 
}
```

My problems are these:
1) The VideoPlayerView seems to lose focus when the video goes to full screen.
2) I can't detect that the video has gone to full screen (the windowDidEnter method doesn't fire)
3) I can't detect that the video has left full screen (the windowDidExit method doesn't fire)

Also as I'm learning Cocoa and Swift, please let me know if this approach is even on the right track.

Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Thanks

**New Information:**
  I've registered for notifications of any view going to full screen and never receive one.  After carefully examining the AVPlayerView as it goes "full screen" it appears that it maybe mimicking the characteristics of being full screen, without actually being "full screen".

Comment: One thought I had was that the AVPlayerView itself isn't going full screen, but one of it's subwindows is.  I found 3 subwindows by iterating through the Views retruned by AVPlayerWindow.subviews (<AVLoadingIndicatorView>,  <AVStatusOverlayView>, <NSView>).  I added a delegate to each in the hopes that I would get a notification if that window went full screen.  So far no luck.  Does anyone know which subwindow goes full screen?

Comment: Why is this a bad question?

Comment: I'm examining containing the AVPlayerView in another View to intercept the keys and determine if the AVPlayerView is in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work around was to not allow the fullscreen button on the AVPlayerView, and control the fullscreen feature manually through a button I created.

Comment: I'm happy to award the bounty to anyone who comes up with an answer, rather than this work around!

Answer (score 2):

I've been experiencing this issue with AVPlayerView also. If I enable the fullscreen button like this:

```
self.playerView.showsFullScreenToggleButton = YES;
```

And I click on the fullscreen button the video goes to fullscreen, however, the app does not take any key inputs and you can't activate Mission Montrol, LaunchPad, etc. This is a very bad user experience and I believe that if you submit an application like this to the Mac App Store it will get rejected. Also I've tried to make my AVPlayerView to become the first responder but it to no avail.

### Solution

So, I looked at how QuickTime Player works in relation to bringing a video in fullscreen. And I noticed that it does not have a button for fullscreen on the player controls. The way it handles fullscreen is by when the user clicks the window's fullscreen control it readjusts the size of the, if I am correct the AVPlayerView or whatever Apple is using. To implement something similar to this do the following:

```
//The window that contains your AVPlayerView set the delegate
 [self.window setDelegate:self];


//So you can respond to these notifications

- (void)windowDidEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification{
        // wait a bit
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                if (self.playerView.isReadyForDisplay == YES) {

        //Make sure the playerView is ready for display

        //Set the playerView to the screen's current frame (Very Important!)
         [self.playerView setFrame:[[NSScreen mainScreen] frame]];

        //Do other UI related things here e.g hide elements e.t.c

        }

        });
        }

- (void)windowWillExitFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification{
//Do other UI related things here e.g show elements e.t.c

}

//If you have a ToolBar in your application do this:

- (NSApplicationPresentationOptions)window:(NSWindow *)window willUseFullScreenPresentationOptions:(NSApplicationPresentationOptions)proposedOptions
{
    return (NSApplicationPresentationFullScreen |
            NSApplicationPresentationHideDock |
            NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideMenuBar |
            NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideToolbar);
}

// To determine if the window is in fullscreen e.g. if the application opened/restored in a fullscreen state the windowDidEnterFullScreen will not be called. So you need to do this:

- (BOOL) isFullScreenMode {
    NSApplicationPresentationOptions opts = [[NSApplication sharedApplication ] presentationOptions];
    if ( opts & NSApplicationPresentationFullScreen) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

#### Conclusion

I hoped that this answered your question. Also, I think this is a bug on Apple's part, so I will file a bug report tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful and I appreciate it.  With respect to Swift, I'd have to go through the example solution and ensure all of the functions and elements are available.